# Unusable disc space

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

I have recently decided to Ubuntu along the windows 7.
when I arrived to the partition management section, I Created a root 30Gb partition from 70Gb usable space, so rest of the space got unusable and i couldn't create /home and swap partition. would you please help me to use this space? I'm a beginner. Thanks.

Comment: How many partitions do you have, and is the disk in MBR or GPT partition layout ? Please update your question with the output from `sudo parted -l`

Comment: If you're a beginner then you might not know that Windows 7 is End-of-Life, unsupported, and shouldn't be used online under no circumstance. Now that you know you may choose the right decision that is to delete it completely and install Ubuntu instead. Or, if you really need a dual-boot, upgrade to Windows 10 before installing Ubuntu. This will save you lots of headaches.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 will automatically create a home directory an swap file in the root, (/), partition. you can modify your partitions using GParted from your Live USB. If you need to modify your Windows partition use Windows Disk Management.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a partition with this space.
If you cannot, try making a Windows 7 ISO and reinstalling everything on the hard drive.
You cannot extend live EXT4 partitions.
This could also be full of bad sectors which is essentially poison and could be why you can't use the space.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix it by running the Ubuntu installation tool from your BIOS. If you set Ubuntu to install alongside (notice the alongside, please) Windows 7, which will pop up when you are selecting installation options, it should automatically install Ubuntu the same way that you are trying to install it, without errors (unless you stop the installation for some reason)

It should work similarly if you would make an attempt to reinstall Windows 7. You can select where and how to install Windows 7, which would involve creating a new partition.